# SQL - Find the two closest date after a specific date

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Dear Stack Overflow community,

I am looking for the *patient id* where the two consecutive dates after the very first one are less than 7 days.

So differences between 2nd and 1st `date <= 7` days

and differences between 3rd and 2nd `date <= 7` days

Example:

```
ID           Date
1          9/8/2014
1          9/9/2014
1          9/10/2014

2          5/31/2014
2          7/20/2014
2          9/8/2014
```

For patient 1, the two dates following it are less than 7 days apart.

For patient 2 however, the following date are more than 7 days apart (50 days).

I am trying to write an SQL query that just output the patient id "1".

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I think you should show the code that you have by this time.

Comment: What if you have more than three rows for a given id?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a working code when I wrote this post. I do not know how to index in SQL the same way as python or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `lead()`, but this is complicated because you want this only for the first three rows.  I think I would go for:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(date, 1) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date,
             lead(date, 2) over (partition by id order by date) as next_date_2,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and
      next_date <= date + interval '7' day and
      next_date2 <= next_date + interval '7' day;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, this seems to be what I needed. Lead function is working quite well!
I actually used the function lead with an argument within, being lead(date, 1) and lead(date, 2) to get the first date and the second date.

Comment: @Vinci . . . Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using window function lag()

```
select * from
(
select id,date,lag(date) over(order by date) as prevdate
from tablename
)A where datediff(day,date,prevdate)<=7
```